# Ruby Rails method evaluation query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to understand how exactly the following method works and what it is saying, I know what it does, but I want to grasp the exact workings of it. I think I understand the =|| operator but I'm not 100% clear on how the 'if' on the second half of the equation works:

```
def current_user 
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id] 
end
```

The method checks to see if the current user is logged in.

To my understanding it evaluates to either true or false but I'm not sure exactly how!

Comment: Have a look at this article [What Ruby’s ||= (Double Pipe / Or Equals) Really Does](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
```

is equivalent to

```
if session[:user_id]
  if !@current_user
    @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
  @current_user
end
```

This expression results in

1. user object - when there's `session[:user_id]`
2. nil - when there's no `session[:user_id]`
3. exception - when there's `session[:user_id]`, but it does not correspond to any existing user in the DB.

Comment: Instead of `if !@current_user`, you may want to use `if @current_user.nil?`

Comment: No worries,  I was thinking if OP has confusion with respect to boolean return values when non-boolean variables are used, then, it would help to avoid such expression..  I like the way you simplified the whole expression - except for `!` usage.

Comment: @WandMaker: btw, your proposed code is not what `||=` operator actually does. :)

Comment: You could replace `if !` with `unless`

Answer (score 1):

It's basically saying to set @current_user, but if it doesn't exist yet than do the following to set current user( the `||=` part). The next part is saying that if the current session has a user_id attached to it, ie `if session[:user_id]`, then find the user of this session based on that user_id and store them in the @current_user instance variable.

Hope that helps

Justin

Comment: The modifier `if` is evaluated before the conditional assignment, i.e. the expression `a ||= b if c` is equivalent to `(a ||= b) if c`, not `a ||= (b if c)`.

Comment: Your answer is difficult to comprehend - you may want to read it again and see if you want to re-phrase it for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If `session[:user_id]` is present, then return instance variable `@current_user` *in case it is set* (i.e. not `nil` or `false`), otherwise assign it to `User.find(session[:user_id])` and then return.